# Cantor Set in Alexander Horned Sphere Construction

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, spheres, cantor-set

I have seen it said in several different places that in the standard construction of the [Alexander horned sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere), given by successive embeddings of a sphere with $2^n$ handles, either limited or intersected, a Cantor set shows up as a place where certain aspects of the construction have to be modified, or where otherwise something interesting happens (I know I should give a more precise description, but it is such a standard construction  that that would seem somewhat superfluous). In Hatcher, this Cantor set is said to correspond to the intersection of all the handles. However, I am unable to see what this set looks like, and I definitely don't understand what makes this set special. If anyone could help explain this phenomena I would be very grateful.

Comment: your question isn't very clear. the cantor set is obviously embedded if you consider the endpoints of the tori in the link (minus the initial [0,1] line), and in the link, the 'handles' don't intersect.

Comment: what do you mean, by "the endpoints of the tori"?

Comment: in the picture in your link the image is of a torus with a segment removed. The two endpoints are therefore the two areas of the torus still attached to the original torus that would have touched the removed segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with a cool video of an Alexander Horned Sphere being constructed for YouTube:

[A YouTube construction of Alexander Horned Sphere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pe2mnrLUYFU)

We can see an obvious connection to the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) by using an address system to identify a 1-1 connection between torus's at different levels of the construction and the different levels of Cantor's construction.

Reading Allen Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) we find the material related to the question on pages 170-171.

The key point behind Hatcher's construction is that the handles (which form the starting point for the defined homeomorphisms $h_n:B_{n-1}\to B_n$) are initially left intact. The $h_n$ remove a section from each handle of the $B_{n-1}$ ball, and build two new interlocking handles in its place. This is different from the construction in the video, which is purely constructive.

Next a map $f$ is defined as $f:B_0\to \mathbb{R^3}$, where $f=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}{h_n h_{n-1} \dots h_1 h_0}$. If we define an additional function $f_N=h_N\dots h_0$ we can see what happens next better.

We are looking at the points of $f_N(B_0)$ that are not in $f(B_0)$ for some $N$. These are the points that never stabilize as part of a handle. If we start with $f_1(B_0)=B_1$, remembering that the next level of handles are still intact, we have a certain set of points. At the next level, $f_2(B_0)=h_2(f_1(B_0))=B_2$, (and so we have $B_n\subset B_{n-1}$) we remove the sections from the two handles, and add four intact new interlocking handles, which is giving us a 'growing' Cantor set related to the missing points.

I'm not sure about the next bit - the image of $f_N(B_0)-B_0$, i.e. $f(f_N(B_0)-f(B_0))$, appears to be an arbitrary null point, because the points are just deleted. And anyway I don't see what the 'intersection of all the handles' means, because they don't intersect, and if you re-complete the missing section, the other handles get obliterated.

Comment: I believe “the intersection of all handles” is supposed to mean the intersection of the sets $X_i \setminus B_i$ for for all $i$, which is a descending sequence of spaces each consisting of $2^i$ handles.